# How do I adopt the PostgreSQL naming convention in legacy database?

Tags: postgresql, identifier

I realize I'll need to update the queries, but if I have a database that has [`camelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or spaces in it, you have to use double quotes on the identifiers (viz. schema, table, column). How do I migrate away from taking into account that I can't have capital letters, nor spaces in my identifiers. I need to normalize all of them to [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Moving to PostgreSQL convention

In PostgreSQL by convention and with good reason, we neither use spaces nor capital letters in our identifiers (columns, tables, schemas, etc). The use of `_` is purely style though. In this example, we

1. Transliterate all `' '` to `'_'`
2. Migrate from `camelCase` to [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)

This code changes nothing, but outputs the respective `ALTER` commands to update the schema (including the schema, table, and column names)

```
-- Columns first.
SELECT FORMAT(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I RENAME COLUMN %I TO %I;',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  lower(
    -- replace all spaces with _, xX and Xx becomes x_x
    regexp_replace(
      -- First, replace spaces with an _
      replace(column_name, ' ', '_'),
      '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
      '\1_\2',
      'g'
    )
  )
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name ~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'

-- Tables
UNION ALL
  SELECT FORMAT (
    'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I RENAME TO %I;', 
    table_catalog,
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    lower(
      regexp_replace(
        replace(table_name, ' ', '_'),
        '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
        '\1_\2',
        'g'
      )
    )
  )
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_name ~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'

-- Schemas
UNION ALL
  SELECT FORMAT (
    'ALTER SCHEMA %I RENAME TO %I;',
    schema_name,
    lower(
      regexp_replace(
        replace(schema_name, ' ', '_'),
        '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
        '\1_\2',
        'g'
      )
    )
  )
  FROM information_schema.schemata
  WHERE schema_name ~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]';
```

From there you can edit the commands to be run, delete the ones you don't want, or simply **run `\gexec` if you're using psql** and they will execute.

### Testing

If you wish you can test the above

```
CREATE SCHEMA "myFoo bar";
CREATE TABLE "myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" ( "my foo" int, "myBar" int, "MyBaz" text, "myFooBarBaz" int, "MyFoo Bar Baz" int, "myTestQ" uuid );

                                            format                                             
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ALTER TABLE test.my_foo_bar.foo_bar_my_baz RENAME COLUMN "MyFoo Bar Baz" TO my_foo_bar_baz;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "my foo" TO my_foo;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "myBar" TO my_bar;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "MyBaz" TO my_baz;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "myFooBarBaz" TO my_foo_bar_baz;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "MyFoo Bar Baz" TO my_foo_bar_baz;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME COLUMN "myTestQ" TO my_test_q;
 ALTER TABLE test."myFoo bar"."foo bar myBaz" RENAME TO foo_bar_my_baz;
 ALTER SCHEMA "myFoo bar" RENAME TO my_foo_bar;
(9 rows)
```

**Note** because there is a collision in the above to `my_foo_bar_baz`, you'll see

> ERROR:  column "my_foo_bar_baz" of relation "foo bar myBaz" already exists

That just confirms nothing catastrophic happens if you happen to run into that. *highly unlikely*

Comment: Note that this doesn't output commands to rename everything that is capitalized, just words that are camel case or have spaces in them.